# Blazor WASM and SQLite - setup simple system

Tags: c#, sqlite, installation, blazor, webassembly

A local foundation is doing a campaign where they are going to open a "restaurant" for a few days for charity. As a volunteer I would like to contribute by making a simple cash register system, where they can add dishes themselves, change prices, calculate the total amount to pay per customer and have an inventory of everything sold. (This cash register system does not do complex things like handle payments etc)

I wanted to take this opportunity to learn Blazor WASM, but I was wondering if this is possible? And what would my setup look like the best? I wanted to use SQLite to store the data, since it stores everything in a file... No need for multiple users and the application is only going to be installed on just one machine, so the database really only needs to retain state on that machine.

Would it then be possible to install the PWA on a computer of theirs as well as the db file and would they then be able to use the system? Or would it be best to approach it differently?

It's a bit of a weird question, but I'm not sure what my options are.

Comment: Do you need to use Blazor WASM or are you OK using Blazor Server? Doing this in Blazor Server will be a lot easier since it will let you bypass all the difficulties of working in the browser sandbox.

Comment: Blazor Server is fine as well but can I also make a PWA with it?

Comment: I think it will not be able to run locally then?

Comment: Blazor Server is basically just an ASP.NET server process that serves web UI to a browser (without WASM). You could install the server on their computer as a service and then navigate to localhost in a browser.

Comment: Okey thanks. How can I install it on another machine? Do I really need to setup IIS etc on the other machine? Or can this be done more easilly?

Comment: Don’t need IIS. Try the Blazor Server template in VS, it will build an executable that you can just copy to another computer and run.

Comment: Thanks, is the executable alone enough? I think i need the dll's and wwwroot folder aswel?

Comment: Depends on how you build it; you can build it as a single-file executable that contains all the DLLs. But by default the DLLs are separate and you will need to copy everything in the build output folder, yes.